# Vim plugin for 'auto-closed' parenthesis?

Tags: vim, plugins, configuration, parentheses

I've searched near and far, and not found a plugin that can simply auto-close a set of parenthesis like Textmate. For example:

```
Vim     : (*manually close parens* → )
Textmate: (*Auto closes parens*)
```

If you can describe a plugin for this, I will be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try delimitMate:

https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate

Some plugins listed here as well.. Plus instructions on setting it up yourself:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters

Answer (score 13):

For those of us who want to go the plain `vim` way:

```
ino " ""<left>
ino ' ''<left>
ino ( ()<left>
ino [ []<left>
ino { {}<left>
ino {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O
```

This autocomplete in `insert` mode. Keep in the `vimrc` to avoid typing it everytime
and when we don't want the mapping, we need to escape it using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>v</kbd> before typing the mapped char of `( {` etc.

Answer (score 10):

I use AutoPairs. You can get it here:

https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs.git

If you read the docs, it has a lot of options which cover most eventualities.

Comment: auto-pairs might break some key maps. For instance å does not work on Swedish keyboards (but not Å).

Answer (score 1):

I'm maintaining a plugin that simplifies insertion of balanced bracket-like characters, and that even supports surrounding of words/lines/selection.

https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/#the-bracketing-subsystem

The default bindings for C & C++ are described in [lh-cpp page](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp#brackets).

Comment: this is a good one, although it takes a bit to get through the docs since im using alot of lh stuff and its a bit overwhelming. I still havent quite figured out why it's generating extra artifacts after insertions but only in .vim language files.

Comment: The extract stuff is certainly the placeholders. You can jump to the next placeholder with `<m-del>` if you are using gvim, `<c-j>` (IIRC) with vim. In C & C++, ';' will try to close all the placeholders after the cursor when it is followed by closing parenthesis and closing `"`.
Now, if you have placeholders only in .vim files, and not in other files, we'll have to investigate further. We try do that tomorrow by email or through the tracker on google-code.

Answer (score 0):

Do it purely in vim without plugins and simulating all of the IDEs that exist out there.

```
" # Close brackets automatically, with return
inoremap {<cr> {<cr>}<C-O><S-O>
inoremap (<cr> (<cr>)<c-o><s-o>
inoremap [<cr> [<cr>]<c-o><s-o>
" # Close brackets without return
inoremap ( ()<left>
inoremap { {}<left>
inoremap [ []<left>
" # Two cases below are covered by inoremap <exp>
" inoremap " ""<left>
" inoremap ' ''<left>
" # If you close a bracket that is already closed, it overwrites
inoremap <expr> ) strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == ")" ? "\<Right>" : ")"
inoremap <expr> } strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "}" ? "\<Right>" : "}"
inoremap <expr> ] strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "]" ? "\<Right>" : "]"
inoremap <expr> ' strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "'" ? "\<Right>" : "''<left>"
inoremap <expr> " strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "\"" ? "\<Right>" : "\"\"<left>"
" # enclose a word in normal mode with "'({[
nnoremap ' mmbi'<esc>ea'<esc>`m<right>
nnoremap " mmbi"<esc>ea"<esc>`m<right>
nnoremap ( mmbi(<esc>ea)<esc>`m<right>
nnoremap { mmbi{<esc>ea}<esc>`m<right>
nnoremap [ mmbi[<esc>ea]<esc>`m<right>
" # enclose a selection in visual mode with "'({[
vnoremap ' <Esc>`<i'<Esc>`>a<right>'<Esc>
vnoremap " <Esc>`<i"<Esc>`>a<right>"<Esc>
vnoremap ( <Esc>`<i(<Esc>`>a<right>)<Esc>
vnoremap { <Esc>`<i{<Esc>`>a<right>}<Esc>
vnoremap [ <Esc>`<i[<Esc>`>a<right>]<Esc>
```