# How to insert matching brace in vim MANUALLY?

Tags: vim, editor, braces

There is some text in my buffer

```
[{(lorem) ipsum <cursor here>
```

How can I insert closing brace `}`, then type something, and then insert `]` matching with opening braces `{` and `[`

Let me explain why I need this.

For example I have to type some pure `javascript` code (because the `coffee` machine is out of order at the moment)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var classA = (function(){
     function classA(){}
     <100 lines of code here>
     return classA;
  -->oh, which closing brace should I insert here....!
```

Another case

```
[theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", HostName, @"some/path/here"]] -> huh, what next? How many closing braces am I missing?
```

And why I clarify MANUALLY in the question title. [Because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958357/vim-plugin-for-auto-closed-parenthesis) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883437/how-do-i-get-vim-to-automatically-put-ending-braces) [are](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) [some](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_Parenthesis_And_Brackets_Handling_Easier) [key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316727/automatic-closing-brackets-for-vim) [bindings](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters) [to](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3599) `automatically` [insert](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) closing braces. For example `in ( ()<Left>`. However, I want to insert closing brace only when I need.

I know there is `i_<C-x>_<C-o>` to insert closing `xml` tag. But I don't know how to deal with these ones.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you press `}]` to insert a `}` followed by a  `]`. Obviously.

Comment: @romainl: see my edited post for explanation why I need this

Comment: And see your question going back to 0 now that you have made it better.

Comment: You might want to try to enable manual folding `set fdm=manual` then select all the 100 lines of code and fold them with `zf`. Then you should have the visual blink with the matching parentheses allowing you to manually close it and clearly see which matches.

Comment: @Vitor: it could not be applied for second example

Comment: `set break` should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I come up with this [vim-close-pair](https://github.com/nissassin17/vim-close-pair) plugin.

Just type `<Ctrl-L>` (insert mode), it will find and insert the missing brace automatically.

- Install with [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim):

  - Append `Plugin 'nissasssin17/vim-close-pair` to your `.vimrc` file
  - Restart vim or run `:source ~/.vimrc`
  - Run `:PluginInstall`
- Manual install:

  ```
    git checkout https://github.com/nissassin17/vim-close-pair.git
    cd vim-close-pair
    mkdir -p ~/.vim/plugin
    cp -f plugin/close-pair.vim ~/.vim/plugin/
    mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload
    cp -f autoload/close-pair.vim ~/.vim/autoload/
  ```